# Excluir linhas com um string específico

Tags: r, dataframe

Gostaria de excluir todas as linhas que apresentem "-" na coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos", como faço para excluir? 
Abaixo segue o resultado do comando `dput(censo)` do meu data frame:

```
structure(list(Unidade.da.Federação = c("Rondônia", "Rondônia", 
"Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", 
"Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", 
"Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia"
), Direção.dos.trabalhos.do.estabelecimento.agropecuário = c("Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente"), Grupos.de.área.total = c("Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha"), Utilização.das.terras = c("Lavouras - permanentes", 
"Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - permanentes", 
"Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - permanentes", 
"Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", 
"Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", 
"Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", 
"Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores", "Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores", 
"Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores", "Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores"
), Condição.legal.do.produtor = c("Produtor individual", "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
"Cooperativa", "Sociedade anônima ou por cotas de responsabilidade limitada", 
"Insituição de utilidade pública", "Governo (federal, estadual ou municipal)", 
"Outra condição", "Não se aplica", "Produtor individual", "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
"Cooperativa", "Sociedade anônima ou por cotas de responsabilidade limitada", 
"Insituição de utilidade pública", "Governo (federal, estadual ou municipal)", 
"Outra condição", "Não se aplica", "Produtor individual", "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
"Cooperativa", "Sociedade anônima ou por cotas de responsabilidade limitada"
), Número.de.estabelecimentos.agropecuários.com.área..Unidades. = c("29", 
"4", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "46", "6", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "8", "-", "-", "-"), Área.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários..Hectares. = c("X", 
"X", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "X", "X", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "X", "-", "-", "-"), util1 = c("Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
"Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
"Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
"Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
"Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras "), util2 = c(" permanentes", 
" permanentes", " permanentes", " permanentes", " permanentes", 
" permanentes", " permanentes", " permanentes", " temporárias", 
" temporárias", " temporárias", " temporárias", " temporárias", 
" temporárias", " temporárias", " temporárias", " área para cultivo de flores", 
" área para cultivo de flores", " área para cultivo de flores", 
" área para cultivo de flores")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

Toda posição de um data frame `df` no R pode ser acessada através do comando

```
df[x, y]
```

Em que `x` é a linha de interesse e `y` é a coluna de interesse. Entretanto, ao rodar `df[x, ]`, sem especificar a coluna desejada, o R entende que deve reportar todas as colunas do data frame.

Para selecionar as linhas da coluna `Área.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários..Hectares.` que não sejam iguais a `-`, basta utilizar o operador diferente: `!=`.

Assim, juntando estas duas informações, temos a resposta pretendida:

```
censo[censo$Área.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários..Hectares. != "-", ]
```

Answer (score 1):

O seguinte faz o que a pergunta pede.

```
i_col <- grep("área.dos.estabelecimentos", names(censo), ignore.case = TRUE)
i_linha <- grepl("-", censo[[i_col]])
censo2 <- censo[!i_linha, ]
```